# Enable/Disable Firefox Addons From an External Application

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Is is possible to enable/disable firefox addons from an external application, preferably without using any XPCOM components?
My first thought was to use a console app that modified **[profile dir]/extensions.sqlite** directly,  but this doesn't quite seem to work.
Is this possible?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry?

Comment: Thanks, but that article seems to deal with installing extensions. What I'm looking for is enabling or disabling an extension that is already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to manipulate user-installed add-ons? Manipulating profile data in an unsupported way is generally a bad idea - you have to make lots of assumptions about the format and risk breaking things if that format changes (or something else happens that you didn't expect). The closest thing to a supported manipulation would be adding/removing extensions in the `<profile>/extensions` directory. As of Firefox 4 the extensions there will either be directories (directory name is the extension ID) or packed XPI files (file name is `<extensionID>.xpi`). If an extension is removed from this directory all the necessary uninstall actions will happen automatically. If an extension is added it used to be installed automatically. As of Firefox 8 the user will be asked whether the installation of the add-on should be allowed - and the user needs to confirm it.

Of course all these manipulations assume that Firefox isn't running. Manipulating the profile while Firefox is running is dangerous because some files might be locked, others might be required later in the browsing session and cause breakage if they are missing/changed.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll just have to pursue avenues other than my original idea